# Order Difference in javascript array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an easy way of getting an order difference of two string arrays?

```
var A = ['a', 'b'];
var B = ['b', 'a'];
```

by comparing these two is there an easy way of finding out that they swapped index? i couldnt find anything helpful online and 
i dont really want to go the long and hard way about it as the array i am using is quite big. Using dragtable to reorder columns of my datatable and i am constantly pushing data to it so whenever an order changes i want the specific data to go into their designated column that is why i need it, thanks!

Comment: What is your desired outcome? Do you want a result object that would contain all strings as key and have both indexes saved? e.g. { a: [1, 2], b: [2, 1] } etc

Comment: can you give us some expcted output? what if the arrays have more elements?

Comment: Also, how would you handle duplicate values?

Comment: is the array array elements are unique?

Comment: lets say the array 4 elements, now using the dragtable i move first element from index 0 to index 2, every other element gets down one index so i want to know which element has been moved and to what index , so i guess @noa-dev 's form is the best, having both old and new index and string as key would be great

Comment: the array i use consist of circa 30 strings tho thats why i wanned an easy way first, like comparison of sort

Comment: Ain't the data in your rows an Object with properties? Are they Arrays?

Comment: they are objects but i figured the easiest way of comparing and getting the difference would be to get an array of the header before and after change and compare them somehow

Comment: please provide us the expected output format

Comment: you don't need the difference, you only need the current order of the columns; basically: `newRow = B.map(propName => "<td>" + dataForThisRow[propName] + "</td>");` It's a bit more complex, as some columns may be computed, others may be empty, ... you have to determine how to compute the value for each column, but **for the order** you only need the current order of headers; no diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over one array and compare the index of the current value to the index of same value in the other given array. If both mismatch, you can create map, containing a mismatch matrix for every value which you can use for further computation. See https://jsfiddle.net/f2jL46ke/

```
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const arr2 = ['b', 'c', 'a']

// I am assuming, that both arrays have an equal length
const differences = arr1.reduce((store, value) => {
    const arr1Index = arr1.indexOf(value)
    const arr2Index = arr2.indexOf(value)
    if(arr1Index !== arr2Index) {
        store[value] = [arr1Index, arr2Index]
    }
    return store
}, {})

console.log(differences)
```

With that approach you know A) what strings weren't at the same position in the arrays and B) where they are located in both arrays.

Comment: wouldnt that be a problem since technically every string changes position as the index changes? or am i not getting it right

Comment: Maybe I understood it incorrectly, but as you populate an array, the original indexes never get shifted. You have to actively go, split an array, push in a value and then concatinate the tail back to the array in order to have shifted indexes. As your array grows, the original indexes of the values stay the same

Comment: @PatoSrna would it be a problem? I don't know. It depends on how you intend to use this. So it might not be. This will bild you up a map of which mismatched values and their respective positions in the different arrays. Of course rotating one string from the beginning to the end, like in the example here, means everything is mismatched now but what else would you expect?

Comment: yeah you guyz are right, it clicked,  i am sure this is what i wanted just gotta work out how to process the data aand i should be fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will simply use sort() method

```
var A = ['a', 'b'];
var B = ['b', 'a'];
B=B.sort();
```

and B.sort() retutn ['a', 'b'];

Comment: 1. `.sort()` modifies the data in-place, so you don't need to assign it back to `B`. 2. OP seems to want the difference between the two, not to make them the same.